# Make API call with special characters

Tags: php, laravel

I have built an API.  To perform a search on it, I do something like the following

```
$tableData = DB::table($table)->where('search', $search)->get();
```

This will essentially form a URL like so (with table and search replaced by other values).

```
https://something.com/api/returnSearch/{{table}}/{{search}}
```

My problem is this.  The search item it something along the lines of the following

> something (asda/tesco)

So the complete URL looks like this

```
https://something.com/api/returnSearch/someTable/something (asda/tesco)
```

The problem is the forward slash in the search, seperating asda and tesco.  When I test it out in postman I get

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

So I presume it thinks the forward slash is part of the url.  Is there any way I can avoid this whilst still allowing a search with a forward slash?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide us the script where the API call is made? And have you tried encoding and decoding the url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To include characters in a URL *which have a special meaning in a URL*, you need to escape/encode them according to URL formatting rules. Specifically: [`rawurlencode`](http://php.net/rawurlencode).

```
printf('https://something.com/api/returnSearch/%s/%s',
       rawurlencode($table), rawurlencode($search))

// https://something.com/api/returnSearch/someTable/something%20%28asda%2Ftesco%29
```